# Execute SQL Server 7 DTS on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dts

I believe its possible to run SQL 2000 DTS packages on 2008 with a compatability layer. But is it possible to do the same with DTS packages created on SQL 7? Is there any MS KB or note that points out if this is even a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't found the KB article at Microsoft yet, but [here's](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/17/how-to-set-compatibility-level-for-sql-server-2008-or-2005-database/) a bit more info.  Doesn't look like you can do what you want w/o moving to SSIS.

Version of SQL Server that can be reverted to can be one of the following:

```
60 = SQL Server 6.0
65 = SQL Server 6.5
70 = SQL Server 7.0
80 = SQL Server 2000
90 = SQL Server 2005
100 = SQL Server 2008
```

Note: Compatibility level 60, 65, and 70 [are] no longer available in SQL Server 2008. And future version[s] of SQL Server will support only two (2) prior version[s] of backward compatibility.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Books Online
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx

Only lists SS 2000, 2005 & 2008 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 2005 but not SQL Server 2008. Can you not move it to SSIS?